# Restore word press to previous version

Tags: wordpress

I accidentally delete all file of WordPress with theme file and all configuration that I made, just the Database file is remain, when I install WordPress then Import old DB again WordPress need Installation, is there any way to bring all of my previous changes ?

Answer (score 0):

To restore changes you made to theme files, as well as anything you uploaded to the media library, you would likely need to be able to restore from a backup of your website. (This depends partly on exactly what you accidentally deleted.)

Your host may have a backup. If you do not have your own backup, contact your host. For the future, I highly recommend that you learn and implement one of the numerous backup tools that are available, making sure you know how to restore from those backups if necessary.